# jQuery .click function not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I’m trying to figure out a problem with some jQuery that isn’t working as expected. I have this click function that should open either open a modal or show a text box, depending on how the if/else statement is evaluated, but it’s not working. When I load the page, nothing happens. Yet if I insert a some console.log statements in the code, I can see the “Click Apply” gets logged when I click the button, along with `$(this).siblings(".apply-menu”)`, yet the textbox doesn’t show up.

If I right click on the output from `$(this).siblings(".apply-menu”)` n the console and save it to a variable, and then add `.show()` to it, the box appears, but then disappears immediately when I click on it. There are no errors and I’m struggling to figure out what’s happening here. There are also no other event listeners bound to the button.

```
        $("button[menu='apply']").click(function(){
            console.log("Click Apply");
            if($('body').attr('signed-in') == "false"){
                console.log(true);
                $(this).siblings(".apply-menu").hide(); //hide dropdown for modal
                modal.open({
                    content: $('#signup_form').html(),
                    top: 130
                });
            } else {
                console.log($(this).siblings(".apply-menu"));
                $(this).siblings(".apply-menu").show();
            }
        });
```

Here is the ERB:

```
<div class="dropdown" id='dropdown{{j.id}}'>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <button ng-if="checkIfAppliedToJob(j.id, appIDs) && $(statusIDs).filter([j.status_id]).size() > 0;" class="j-descrip-button thin" disabled>Pending</button>
    <button ng-if="!checkIfAppliedToJob(j.id, appIDs);" class="j-descrip-button thin job-dropdown-link" menu="apply">Apply</button>
    <% else %>
    <button class="j-descrip-button thin job-dropdown-link" menu="apply">Apply</button>
    <% end %>
    <div class="dropdown-menu middle apply-menu">
        <div class="dd_arrow_middle" style='z-index: -1;'></div>
        <div class="apply-dropdown-content">
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <% if !current_user.first_name.present? || !current_user.last_name.present? || !current_user.resume_file_name.present? %>
            <div>Oops! Looks like you need to provide us with some info - go to <%= link_to 'My Account', edit_user_registration_path %> to upload your resume and/or give us your name.</div>
            <% else %>
            <span class="apply-prompt"><%= @apply_question %></span>
            <br>
            <span class="outer-wc"><span class="word-count">0</span>/500 characters</span>
            <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="{{'/applications?id=' + j.id}}" class="pitch-form" data-remote="true" html="{:role=>&quot;form&quot;}" id="{{j.id}}" method="post">
                <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
                    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
                </div>
                <% if defined? @error_msg %>
                <span><%= @error_msg %></span>
                <% end %>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="apply-textbox" id="pitch" name="pitch"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div style="display:none;"><input id="user_id" name="user_id" type="text" value="<%= current_user.id %>"></div> <!-- is this the best way to access the user, are there drawbacks? -->
                <div style="display:none;"><input id="job_description_id" name="job_description_id" type="text" value="{{j.id}}"></div>
                <div style="display:none;"><input id="company_id" name="company_id" type="text" value="<%= @company.id %>"></div>
                <input class="apply-submit-btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit Application">
            </form>
            <% end %>
            <% else  %>
            <div>You have to sign in before you can apply to jobs.</div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the rendered HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="job-title ng-binding" style="background: #53AA2A">Lead Developer</div>
    <div class="job-role ng-binding" id="Ruby Ninja">Ruby Ninja</div>
    <p class="job-description ng-binding">Awesome sauce!</p>
    <div class="btn-holder">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="return !window.open(this.href,'', 'width=720,height=480,location=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');"><button class="j-descrip-button thin">Read More</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown11">
            <!-- ngIf: checkIfAppliedToJob(j.id, appIDs) && $(statusIDs).filter([j.status_id]).size() > 0; -->
            <!-- ngIf: !checkIfAppliedToJob(j.id, appIDs); --><button ng-if="!checkIfAppliedToJob(j.id, appIDs);" class="j-descrip-button thin job-dropdown-link ng-scope" menu="apply">Apply</button><!-- end ngIf: !checkIfAppliedToJob(j.id, appIDs); -->
            <div class="dropdown-menu middle apply-menu">
                <div class="dd_arrow_middle" style="z-index: -1;"></div>
                <div class="apply-dropdown-content">
                    <span class="apply-prompt">What makes you and Ice 2 Go a good fit?</span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="outer-wc"><span class="word-count">0</span>/500 characters</span>
                    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/applications?id=11" class="pitch-form ng-pristine ng-valid" data-remote="true" html="{:role=>&quot;form&quot;}" id="11" method="post">
                        <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
                            <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="apply-textbox" id="pitch" name="pitch"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display:none;"><input id="user_id" name="user_id" type="text" value="1"></div> <!-- is this the best way to access the user, are there drawbacks? -->
                        <div style="display:none;"><input id="job_description_id" name="job_description_id" type="text" value="11"></div>
                        <div style="display:none;"><input id="company_id" name="company_id" type="text" value="3"></div>
                        <input class="apply-submit-btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit Application">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="j-descrip-button thin job-dropdown-link" menu="refer">Refer A Friend</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu right refer-menu">
                <div class="dd_arrow"></div>
                <div class="refer-dropdown-content">
                    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/send_refer_a_friend_email" html="{:role=>&quot;form&quot;}" method="post" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="tPFqDeHakW85TmdouG7Qsu9vJ5f+kvpM40MC2rYUPe0="></div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="display: none;">
                            <label for="company_name">Company Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="company_name" name="company_name" type="text" value="Ice 2 Go">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                            <label for="job_title">Job Title</label>
                            <input id="job_title" name="Ruby Ninja" type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div style="font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><b>You're an awesome friend!</b></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user_full_name">Your Name</label>  <!-- is this the best way to do this? -->
                            <div>
                                <input class="refer-text-field" id="user_full_name" name="user_full_name" type="text" value="Daniel Bonnell">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span><label for="friend_email">Your Friend's Email</label> <em style="font-size: 10px;">use commas for multiple emails</em></span>
                            <div>
                                <input class="refer-text-field" id="friend_email" name="friend_email" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="prof-link" style="display: none;">
                            <label for="prof_link">Profile Link</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="prof_link" name="prof_link" type="text" value="http://localhost:3000/ice-2-go">
                        </div>
                        <input class="refer-submit-btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Send to My Friend(s)">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Next time you ask a question with this much code it might be helpful to make a jsfiddle so someone can answer your question quicker & easier.

I used the rendered HTML you supplied, I then changed the query a little, to show you a couple things, there is only one sibling to that button (that's why there are two jsfiddles 1st one is without the `.siblings(".apply-menu")` & I used `.toggle()` instead of `.show()` since at least in the rendered HTML it was already showing.

**Fiddle 1:** http://jsfiddle.net/4t0nm1zt/1/

**Fiddle 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/4t0nm1zt/2/

Also take a look at [this siblings link](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/), mainly the Unique siblings portion of the 1st example/demo, notice how it says 7, and not 11.

Hope that helps

Comment: I think my Angular code might be to blame. I tried implementing your suggestions, which make sense to me, but the textbox still won't appear. I copy/pasted the parts of my Angular code that are needed for the view in question into a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4t0nm1zt/1/) and was able to reproduce the problem. Now if you click the 'Apply' button, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out the problem. In another js file I have a .click function bound to elements with the `.dropdown-menu` class that is canceling out my new click function. See code below:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('.dropdown-link').click(function(e) {
    toggleDropdown(e, '#' + $(this).attr('menu'));
});
```

I don't know why, but it hadn't occurred to me to just copy all my js files into the jsFiddle and see which one caused the breakage.

Comment: that would do it, the best way to design systems and to test issues is to keep it simple, which is not always easy.

Comment: Especially when you're making modifications to a system someone else designed. It's not always clear what's going on in the background.